# How to properly call mainactivity from library module on app module

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I call an activity on library module from app module the app crashes

There's a button on the app module and when it's pressed it will call an activity from the library module but every time I do that the app just crashes

Below is the code on the app module in which the intent will call a main activity on library module

```
 //Audio Activity
    audioButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IV_main_audio);
    audioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new 
    Intent("com.danielkim.soundrecorder.MainActivity");
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }

    });
```

Here is the android manifest on the app module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.kiminonawa.mydiary">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".shared.MyDiaryApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">

    <!-- Add this key for search the place name -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDVL96wY3-Xqe8Rjt065Low6hMCOjW-Qd4" />



    <activity
        android:name=".init.InitActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme_NoActionBar_FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".contacts.ContactsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".entries.DiaryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".entries.photo.PhotoOverviewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme_NoActionBar_FullScreen" />
    <activity
        android:name=".entries.photo.PhotoDetailViewerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".memo.MemoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".setting.SettingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".main.AboutActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".security.PasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".backup.BackupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <!-- Ucrop -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <!-- Start For NoNonsense-FilePicker -->
    <activity
        android:name=".backup.DirectoryPickerActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FilePickerTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- This is for Android N -->
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:resource"
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/nnf_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <!-- End For NoNonsense-FilePicker -->


    <activity android:name=".main.CollageFragment"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Instead of writing solved in the title and explaining what you did in the question body, make your own answer, and mark your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, reflection can be used to start your Activity from libary module :

> Class.forName("com.mypackage.MainActivity")

```
try {
    Intent myIntent = new 
    Intent(this,Class.forName("com.danielkim.soundrecorder.MainActivity"));
    startActivity(myIntent);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: i'll be adding this on the app module or library module??

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i=new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: how can I differentiate on which activity I'm trying to call. Because both app module and library module has MainActivity on them

Comment: I did this and it still crashes

 Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.danielkim.soundrecorder.activities.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: Here's the logcat crash report https://imgur.com/a/FECU0xL

I converted the com.danielkim.soundrecorder from an app module into a library module and that's why I'm using as a library.

Answer (score 0):

```
audioButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IV_main_audio);
audioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        try{
            // try another constructor
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), "com.danielkim.soundrecorder.MainActivity");
            // add optional flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK if necessary.
            // intentLoadNewActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("TAG",e);// if still not work, please show us the log.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where can I see the log?? sorry I'm new at using android studio

Comment: @DatsiK77 press `alt + 6`, or  `Logcat` on the bottom tool bar. See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: I cannot see what went wrong, please set the filter to `only selected application` on the right top of the logcat plane. And input the `TAG` you used when logging into the middle top input plane.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I solved it already after some searching. I just had a duplicate filename on the app module and the library module.